# Why is x^0 = x?

Tags: bit-manipulation, logical-operators, xor

I have a very simple question.

Why is a number when `XOR`'ed with 0 gives the number itself.

Can someone please give the proof using an example.

Lets say I have the number 5

`5^0==>`

I think the answer should be just the last bit of 5 `XOR'ed` with 0, but the answer is still 5.

Comment: Think of it this way: XOR is equivalent to addition mod 2 for each pair of binary digits. If you add 0 to a number it won't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is there that you did not understand. Please read about [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate)

```
00000101 // = 5
00000000 // = 0
--------
00000101 // = 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I got confused with another thing I read somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

0 is false, and 1 is true.

As per the definition, XOR operation `A XOR B` is "A or B, but not, A and B". So, since B is false, so the result will be A.

Also, [XOR truth table shows that it outputs true whenever the inputs differ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table):

```
Input   Output

A   B   XOR Result
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   0
```

As you can see, whatever be the value of A, if it is XORed with 0, the result is the bit itself.

So, as you say:

```
 5 = 101, 0 = 000
 When performing XOR operation on the individual bits:

 101
 000
----
 101  = 5.
```

Hence, the result of X^0 is X itself.

Answer (score 0):

Bit-wise operations operates on set of bits in number - not just on last bit.
So if you perform some bit-wise operation on 32-bit integer, then all 32 bits are affected. So integer `5` is `0.....0000101 (32 bits)`. If you need just the resulting last bit after `xor` operation apply binary `AND` with `1`:

```html
<script>
console.log("%i\n",(5^0)&1);
console.log("%i\n",(6^0)&1);
</script>
```